# What is the difference between a paginated and a non-paginated PDF/DjVu file?

Tags: pdf, ebook, djvu

I heard that some PDF or DjVu files are not paginated. Pagination would help adding bookmarks to these files. All PDF and DjVu files I have seen are files consisting of pages of content.

So I wonder what a PDF/DjVu file that is not paginated looks like, and what it will look like after pagination?

Answer (score 2):

From [Princeton WordNet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=pagination):

> S: (n) **pagination**, *folio, page number, paging* (the system of numbering pages)

That explains the whole shebang. Basically: Take anything arbitrarily long and split it into pages.

An unpaginated file, although I've never seen one, would be just a stream of content, whereas a paginated one would obviously consist of a countable number of pages.

Take a browser showing an HTML page as an analogy: It's unpaginated. When you decide to print it, it becomes paginated because of the way our printers work and we humans choose to read nowadays. The tricky part of course is defining where pages should start and end, and the fact that with the pagination, you create logical or physical boundaries that weren't there before.

Then again, the problem with working with unpaginated content is that most current software is based on pagination, from Word to Acrobat. PDF does not seem to support this. DjVu might, although I didn't find a proof and I'm not experienced with DjVu itself.

Comment: Thanks! By "PDF does not seem to support this", what do you mean to be supported by pdf? Are there some examples of unpaginated pdf and djvu files?

Comment: "working with unpaginated content". You would need to create a PDF with really large page sizes to achieve this effect. As for DjVu, I honestly don't know. Haven't read the DjVu specification, but its "About" site speaks of pages, so DjVu probably relies on pagination internally. If you have an example of an unpaginated file (as you said in your question), feel free to share it.

Comment: I don't have such examples which is why I asked for them in my post and comment.

Comment: No, sorry for the confusion, I meant, you said that "you heard", so maybe you could share where you heard that :)